# Authentication with Uber API using NSURLSession

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, uber-api

I am using `NSURLSession` to get JSON data using the [Uber API](https://developer.uber.com/v1/endpoints/). 
I have a server token and a client ID and a `Secret`. 
How can I update the following code in order to authenticate and pass parameters (server token, latitude and longitude)?

```
    let urlPath = "https://api.uber.com/v1/products"

    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            println(error)
        }
        else {
            let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
            println(jsonResult)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Maybe looked at `dataTaskWithRequest:...` and changing the headers for the NSURLRequest?

Comment: I tried using NSMutableURLRequest with dataTaskWithRequest but without great success. I keep getting the response "No authentication provided" despite adding values like server token, client ID and secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation at https://developer.uber.com/v1/auth/, you need to include the token as an HTTP header.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = // Setup rest of request.
[request setValue:[@"Token " stringByAppendingString:<token>] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
// Create and resume data task from request.
```

Comment: BTW I'm assuming you can get past the initial authorization and can get an access token.

Comment: I do have an access token, but I can’t get passed the authentication. 
I get “code = unauthorized; message = "No authentication provided."

Here is the updated code: 

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.setValue(uberServerToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "server_token")
request.setValue("37.7758181", forHTTPHeaderField: "latitude")
request.setValue("-122.418028", forHTTPHeaderField: "longitude")

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

// etc.

Comment: You're setting the header wrong, at least according to the docs. See my answer; in Swift it'd be `request.setValue("Token \(uberServerToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")`.